# Unable to center text in span when position:absolute is used

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-position

I am facing weired behaviour with `span` when its position is controlled by `absolute`.
I want to center text in a circle.

```css
.close-icon {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  height: 0.75rem;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 0.75rem;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.625rem;
  top: 0.375rem;
}
```

```html
<span class="close-icon">X</span>
```

Output: [image: output with absolute]

Without Position `absolute`:

```
background: red;
border-radius: 50%;
color: #ffffff;
display: flex;
font-size: 0.5rem;
height: 0.75rem;
justify-content: center;
width: 0.75rem;
align-items: center;
```

Output: [image: output without absolute]

I am not able to find any solution or reason why this is happening. It would be great if someone can put some light on this behaviour.

PS: When I remove `right: 0.625rem` then it is perfectly aligned to center.

Comment: Your example is working just fine with Google Chrome Version 81.0.4044.113 - which browser are you using?

Comment: @Toni Version 81.0.4044.113

Comment: If you increase the size of the element and the text, it works? I've tried it and i could only reproduce the problem on tiny scale, so it may be a resolution or DPI problem

Comment: for sure sub-pixel rendring since your elements is very small

Answer (score -1):

You can solve it this way:

```
<style>
    .close-icon {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        background: red;
        border-radius: 50%;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 0.5rem;
        height: 0.75rem;
        width: 0.75rem;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    }
</style>
```

But please consider that you need it inside a relative element so it can be positioned in the middle against that element.